# Using SSLv3 with node on legacy application

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I've been messing around with node in the last couple of weeks trying to get my head around enabling SSLv3 to read packets from an old software of mine using the `tls` package.

I am fully aware that SSLv3 is disabled for security reasons, but I went as far as installing `iojs-v3.3.1` but even then when i set `secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'` in the options I get `Error: SSLv3 methods disabled`.

When running node with `--enable-ssl3` I get a warning `node: bad option: --enable-ssl3`. Can anyone please point me to the right direction as to how to enable SSLv3 on a newer version of node? or point me to the last version of node that did not have support for SSLv3 disabled?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the per-version documentation for the TLS module, [Node 9](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/tls.html) was the highest-numbered version to allow SSLv3 in the community build.  However, since [Node 8](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/tls.html) was a Long Term Support release, the Node 8.17.0 release is actually more recent than the final Node 9.x release.

You can take your pick from the historical download page at https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. It's good to know that there is a more recent release with SSLv3. Thinking of maybe proxying the sslv3 request to tcp, is there any abstract example on how to do this?

Comment: I don't know of an abstract example -- it's a very straightforward thing to do in Node.  You could look at, say, https://github.com/tewarid/node-tcp-proxy if you get stuck.  That has more features than you need, but it's still quite small and pretty easy to read.

Comment: Thanks, I already stumbled across it so I guess I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Coming back to this again, before setting up my dev environment. does node 8.17 has SSLv3 support?